# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)

Tags: typescript, enums, intersection

I have an object of two `Domains` plus three `Events` per `Domain`. Now I want to pick one `Event` and its resp. `Domain`. I get the following error.

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
Untitled-1(8, 5): The expected type comes from property 'Event' which is declared here on type
'Group<{ Domain0: Enum<"Event0_0" | "Event0_1" | "Event0_2">; Domain1: Enum<"Event1_0" | "Event1_1" | "Event1_2">; },
"Domain0" | "Domain1">'
```

If I have only one `Domain`, everything is working fine, so I assume, TS takes some kind of intersection, thus type `never`.

```ts
type Enum<K extends PropertyKey> = {
    [key in K]: key;
};

type Events = Record<string, Enum<string>>;

interface Group<events extends Events, domain extends keyof events> {
    Domain: domain;
    Event: keyof events[domain];
};

interface Obj<events extends Events> {
    Group: Group<events, keyof events>;
};

const obj: Obj<{
    Domain0: Enum<"Event0_0" | "Event0_1" | "Event0_2">,
    Domain1: Enum<"Event1_0" | "Event1_1" | "Event1_2">,
}> = {
    Group: { Domain: "Domain0", Event: "Event0_0" },
};
```

`Enum<"a" | "b">` simply is an object of shape

```ts
{
    a = "a",
    b = "b",
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example so we can run the compiler locally and verify the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through this step-by-step.

You are passing the following object into `Obj` as `events`.

```
{
    Domain0: Enum<"Event0_0" | "Event0_1" | "Event0_2">,
    Domain1: Enum<"Event1_0" | "Event1_1" | "Event1_2">,
}
```

This object type and its keys are passed to `Group`. The type of `domain` is `keyof events` which evaluates to:

```
"Domain0" | "Domain1"
```

For the `Event` property, you compute `keyof events[domain]`. Fully expanded, this would look like this:

```
keyof {
    Domain0: Enum<"Event0_0" | "Event0_1" | "Event0_2">,
    Domain1: Enum<"Event1_0" | "Event1_1" | "Event1_2">,
}["Domain0" | "Domain1"]
```

`events[domain]` would evaluate to

```
Enum<"Event0_0" | "Event0_1" | "Event0_2"> 
  | Enum<"Event1_0" | "Event1_1" | "Event1_2">
```

which is a union of two object types which do *not* share any properties. Calling `keyof` on this union therefore produces `never`.

```
keyof (
  | {
      Event0_0: "Event0_0";
      Event0_1: "Event0_1";
      Event0_2: "Event0_2";
    }
  | {
      Event1_0: "Event1_0";
      Event1_1: "Event1_1";
      Event1_2: "Event1_2";
    }
)
// -> never
```

---

To achieve your initial goal, you have to compute a *union* of valid `Domain`/`Event` combinations.

```
type Group<E extends Events> = {
    [K in keyof E]: {
        Domain: K;
        Event: keyof E[K];
    }
}[keyof E]

interface Obj<E extends Events> {
    Group: Group<E>;
}
```

Which leads to the following result:

```
let obj: Obj<{
    Domain0: Enum<"Event0_0" | "Event0_1" | "Event0_2">,
    Domain1: Enum<"Event1_0" | "Event1_1" | "Event1_2">,
}>

obj = {
    Group: { Domain: "Domain0", Event: "Event0_0" },
};
obj = {
    Group: { Domain: "Domain0", Event: "Event1_0" },
//  ^^^^^ Type '"Domain0"' is not assignable to type '"Domain1"
};
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgVwLYB4DSUIA9gTgEwGcoAFAJwHtIzQ0IQA+KAXigG8AoKbqAbQGt6UAJZwoaALoAuKIJABuDgF9FHUJFgA3PMGKsAShADGFMvhSFgZUQHMANLESpL1uDYYNV66AHFKCMBQYTBw8Ii0dQiZWTh4+DFFZegoAM1hpdi44ngARCiQAQ1EZNEVsnhhtOGAZOVTYXkkyniVlAWS0mAkODlFcMhSCo2gAeQAjACsgkNwCYkrIpliePwoAmVWAoM9lHo4AGwhgKApJmXGp5e48wtEABhl4ZBQAIgXqu4B9O5eoAB8oG8qsAvgBGX4AoE6L4AJheDDsWWu+SKcFBjycr3ewFB3whgOxuPB-wJwNxcIRygYPVOExYmTimzAMjYUBuqJkL3Z9xeDmxnOxXx+UCUiJUHFp9KuUCZLLZKOKgO5cB+fOBArJeJFiIA9DruAA9I1GqAAFXA0AA5FyFSqXpaRMQ4BRjgVCIRhDY4AUxocoMAKP6LVBrcrwcp5EA)

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer, that helped alot!